# Matrix and Binomial Coefficients

Tags: number-theory, matrices, binomial-coefficients, puzzle

Considering the construction of a matrix as follows.

The $n$th row in the matrix is filled with the coeffcients of $x^r$ in the expansion of $(1+x)^n$ from the columns $2n$ to $3n$ inclusive and circle all the numbers that are divisible by $n$ in the same row

How would I find the number of columns for which all the elements in a column are circled in the first j columns given j = 547 ?

Comment: "How would I find the number of _columns_ for which all the elements in a _column_ are circled in the first j _columns_ given j = 547 ?" It feels that one of the "_columns_" must actually read "_rows_". Is the question correct?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Have you tried looking at Pascal's triangle modulo some small primes?  You could see a pattern that would apply.  The [Divisibility properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) section of Wikipedia's Binomial Coefficient article has some useful information.  [This page](http://ecademy.agnesscott.edu/~lriddle/ifs/siertri/Pascal.htm) has some neat images mod 2.

Comment: Is the answer `547C2` where nCr = n!/(r!*(n-r)!) ?

Comment: Can you please provide some more insight?

Comment: It can't be that big.  You only have 547 columns to consider.  Start with 3's.  In row 3, columns 6 through 9 have 1, 3, 3, and 1, and you circle the two 3's in 7 and 8.  Row 4 has 1,4,6,4,1 in columns 8 through 12 and you circle the 4's in 9 and 11.  So column 8 doesn't have all the numbers circled, but 7 does.  If you make a spreadsheet going up to 20 or so you will probably see the pattern.

Comment: Could I get an explanation for the downvote?

Comment: Also, any row that is a multiple of 2 or 3 will have a 1 in it (like row 3 in my example), which you won't circle.  So you only have to consider rows of the form 6k+1 and 6k+5.